# Can we see the results of our community evaluation?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, site-evaluation

Back when beta evaluations were conducted by meta post, people could see how other members of the community felt about the site.  Each question under review had a net score indicating it was considered good, "meh", or bad and underneath was a [discussion in the comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155739/can-we-have-comments-and-or-separate-q-and-a-voting-for-the-new-community-eval) where people could justify their vote and propose ideas on how to make the site better.

This was useful because you could see on what types of questions the community was in agreement on and where they disagreed.  The latter often pointed to areas where maybe the quality expectations were unclear, or there was a lack of clarity on site scope, or a number of other things that might merit further discussion.

Now that everything is done in the review queues, most of that is now gone (unless you're a moderator).  You can manually go through the profiles of everyone on the recently reviewed list and tabulate votes to figure out what people thought about each question, but that's pretty inefficient once a site becomes big enough to have a lot of people vote.  The comments are also [completely gone](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155739/can-we-have-comments-and-or-separate-q-and-a-voting-for-the-new-community-eval) unless someone starts up a meta post.

Can we make the moderator summary visible to all users who are eligible to participate in the community evaluation?  That would help the site's community see if everyone is on the same page or identify areas we need to work on to do better on the next review.

Comment: There is a mod only summary, that's more or less what you want. Perhaps you could update your request to make that summary available to all users (or users over a certain rep threshold). It's a bit silly that [reviewers can see each others' evaluations](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166222/can-we-inform-users-that-the-choices-they-make-when-filling-out-a-community-eval), but not the summary.

Comment: @Yannis: Mods are allowed to share the summary, though.

Comment: Just ask your mod... there is no need to make a big deal of it. Jeff has said several times in the past that stuff is hidden to avoid dumping info on unsuspecting users (mods are fairly used to it) and all that the user/community needs to do is ask the mod and they can give a summary/post it as long as sensitive information (in this case, none) is withheld.

Comment: @Manishearth I wouldn't share without checking with SE first, as with _any_ mod only piece of information. And if there's no reason for the summary to be mod only, then "ask a mod" is a waste of time for everyone involved.

Comment: I for one intend to post on meta with the results from the site I'm a moderator on.  Hopefully that will also be the place to gather the sorts of comments you miss (as do I).  FYI: having created my own self-evaluation, the old way was a pain in the neck and a fully automated eval is totally worthwhile.  (@Yannis: I already asked if we can share it and got the necessary permission.)

Comment: @Yannis: SE _gave_ permission. Lemme look for it..

Comment: @Manishearth I'm not doubting that you talked about this with SE prior to sharing the summary, what I'm saying is that it's a waste of time and the summary should be publicly available.

Comment: @JonEricson Yeah, I agree _doing_ the evaluation itself is smoother now.  But I'm a little concerned we get less out of the evaluation with the review queues.

Comment: @Yannis: Ah. I agree with that part :) Though I guess the point is to keep the results secret till the eval gets over. Publishing the general trend may skew voting (I doubt it though)

Comment: @Manishearth But... but... but... you can already [see how other people are voting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166222/can-we-inform-users-that-the-choices-they-make-when-filling-out-a-community-eval), if skewing voting was a concern, voting histories wouldn't be public.

Comment: @Yannis: Ah, but you _can't_ see how all the users are voting at once (that happens in the review history for mods only, IIRC). You can only pick a certain user and check out their eval. Again, I agree with the feature req.  Just thinking out loud why SE would make the feature like this :S

Comment: @Manishearth Besides, in the process of the eval, about half the questions in there I ended up editing, which surely skewed the voting results anyway for people voting later.

Comment: @Manishearth It's only 10 questions, I got the general feeling of how people are voting in less than a minute in all three sites I care enough to vote in comm. evals. And since I got a diamond on the one site and can see both the vote history and the summary, there's really no difference.

Comment: @Troyen: Yeah.. on the Chem.SE eval (in the old, meta post style), I held off on my urges to fix things, and then did so after it got over.

Comment: We are going to address the commenting issue with [an automated meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/166562/155160). I agree that showing the final results makes sense... and I'll try to find a good spot for that. (Maybe added to that meta post, or linked from it, or *something*.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When an evaluation completes, we now post the result summary as an answer on the [automated meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/166562/155160) that will be created at the start of the evaluation.

You can see an example of one [here](https://fitness.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/466/lets-get-critical-may-2013-site-self-evaluation/468#468), though for convenience, here's a picture of what it looks like:

[image: Image of a review, the same one linked earlier]

Comment: Wow, "Community♦" is getting more and more involved in the, urr, community!.

Comment: @Grace why picture and not quote? I was going to edit but then stopped wondering if there was a reason behind this.

Comment: @ShaWiz No real reason. But it gives me a solid image that I can link in any context I want, unlike text that is subject to the medium it is presented in.